# Custom Segue Warning Attempt to present "X" on "Y" whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, segue

I have a custom segue so that views cross fade, instead of display bottom to top.

When the segue happens from a button, it works well, but when I do it programatically, after a UIAlertController, I get 'Attempt to present "x" on "y" whose view is not in the window hierarchy'. And, if I try to unwind to the presenter view, the app crashes, or it just won't do anything.

If instead of using my custom segue, I use a default "show" segue, I don't get an error, and unwinding occurs as expected.

Here's my custom segue (based on http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/):

```
class TransitionManagerFade: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
        var unwind = false

        var firstVCView = sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        var secondVCView = destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        if identifier == "SingleDeviceToRootView" || identifier == "MPToRootView" || identifier == "SingleEndToRootView" {

            unwind = true
        }


        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        secondVCView.alpha = 0

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)


        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: { () -> Void in

            firstVCView.alpha = 0
            secondVCView.alpha = 1

            }) { (Finished) -> Void in

                if unwind {

                    self.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

                } else {
                    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                        animated: false,
                        completion: nil)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the custom segue is fine. You need to check your present and unwind code

Comment: @dopcn could it be that the default segue is faster than the custom?